# MySQL generating monthly breakdown from date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, date

good morning,

I have a nagging issue I cannot really solve.. I have a database table like this, showing resources spent (value) in a date range by person:

```
    id,name,startdate,enddate,value
    --------------------------------
    10,John,2012-01-14,2012-10-30,200000
    11,Jack,2012-02-01,2012-08-01,70000
    12,John,2012-05-01,2012-06-01,2000
```

I need a query that creates the result like this, summarizing the 'value' by month, taking partial months into account

```
month, name, value
------------------    
2012-01, John, 9000
2012-02, John, 18000
2012-03, John, 18000
2012-04, John, 18000
2012-05, John, 20000
2012-06, John, 18000
2012-07, John, 18000
2012-08, John, 18000
2012-01, John, 18000
2012-02, Jack, 10000
2012-03, Jack, 10000
2012-04, Jack, 10000
2012-05, Jack, 10000
2012-06, Jack, 10000
2012-07, Jack, 10000
2012-08, Jack, 0
```

Now I know how I'd do this procedurally (like with PHP) with a loop: get the daily amount, then check month by month how many days spent there according to the range and multiply it by the daily amount.

thanks
peter

Comment: Do you have a separate table for people  (eg. Employees if the names here are names of employees)?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, I have a separate table for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a calendar table and can't create one, you can simulate a virtual calendar table in your query. Here's a query that should answer your question, that makes use of such a virtual table:

```
select m.startmonth,
       e.name, 
       coalesce(sum(r.value *
                    datediff(case when adddate(m.startmonth, interval 1 month) <
                                       r.enddate 
                                  then adddate(m.startmonth, interval 1 month) 
                                  else r.enddate end,
                             case when m.startmonth > r.startdate 
                                  then m.startmonth else r.startdate end) / 
                    datediff(r.enddate,r.startdate)),0) valueshare
from
(select cast('2012-01-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-02-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-03-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-04-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-05-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-06-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-07-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-08-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-09-01' as date) startmonth union all
 select cast('2012-10-01' as date) startmonth) m
cross join employees e
left join resources_spent r 
       on r.enddate > m.startmonth and 
          r.startdate < adddate(m.startmonth, interval 1 month) and
          r.name = e.name
group by m.startmonth, e.name
order by 2,1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53dfe/15).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, there is a quite lot to learn here for me! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, Peter! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a calendar table with one row for each date.  Other fields would be whatever is useful to you, such as fiscal periods, holidays, whatever.

Then, for your report, you could create a temp table and populate it like this:

```
insert into YourTempTable
(id, date, amount)
select id, c.datefield, amount
from YourTable join Calendar c on datefield >= startdate
and datefield <= enddate
where whatever
```

From there, you select from YourTempTable and YourTable, joining on the id.